# Laravel 4: avoid duplicate entry

Tags: laravel, duplicates, laravel-4, newsletter

In my app there is a simple form with one field (email) that give the possibility to register to the newsletter.

If i entry a new email, all it works fine.
If i entry an email that already exists in the database i get the error SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry...
Because i had defined that field as unique in the database.

All i want to do is to redirect::back()->with('message', 'email already registered')
But i do not know how can i do this?
I can just put an if statement in the method controller?
Or i have to define it in $rules in the model, adding another rule:

```
public static $rules = array(
    'email' => 'required',);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define a [unique rule](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-unique) on your users table:

```
public static $rules = array(
    'email' => 'required|unique:users|email');
```