# Laravel Built-In User Auth

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I am using Laravel's Auth package for user registration and login. While registration, along with email, I have kept a `roll_no` field as unique.

Now when I register twice with the same email Id, it gives me a error message saying that this Email already exists in our records. But when I register twice with the same roll no, it throws a SQL Query exception (Instead I want an error msg similar to the case of Email conflict).

Please note that I'm using Laravel 5.1
I've surfed so many blogs and forums but they all answered for Laravel 4.2
There's some difference in these two versions.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I assume you're looking for something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18572994/laravel-4-avoid-duplicate-entry ?

Comment: Of course, modify and add it per your needs   'roll_no' => 'required|unique:users|roll_no');

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not validating `roll_no`. But `email` validation code is already exist in Laravel.

Try this in your `AuthController.php`

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        'roll_no' => 'required|unique:roll_no', //add this line
    ]);
}
```